# Detect hover inside div

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a `parent div` that contains a `child div`. When a user hovers over the `parent div` The `child div's` border color and text should become white.

I've made an example the box with `No score, yet click and submit` text color should become white and the border color white aswel.

```html
<div class="flex w-full p-4">
    <div class="flex hover:bg-black hover:text-white text-black p-2 rounded cursor-pointer items-center w-full">
        <div class="w-1/2">
            <h4> RESTROOM</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="flex flex-wrap xs:w-full xs:mt-2 md:mt-0 w-1/2 py-4 border-black border-2 rounded relative">
            <span class="flex items-center text-black text-xs font-bold uppercase h-full pin-t absolute ml-2">
                No score yet, click and submit
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

How could I detect this? (I use [TailwindCss](https://tailwindcss.com))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.flex:hover .text-black {
  color:#fff;
}

.flex:hover .border-black {
  border-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex w-full p-4">
    <div class="flex hover:bg-black hover:text-white text-black p-2 rounded cursor-pointer items-center w-full">
        <div class="w-1/2">
            <h4> RESTROOM</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="flex flex-wrap xs:w-full xs:mt-2 md:mt-0 w-1/2 py-4 border-black border-2 rounded relative a1">
            <span class="flex items-center text-black text-xs font-bold uppercase h-full pin-t absolute ml-2">
                No score yet, click and submit
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```